# How can I pretty print a quoted list in clojure?

Tags: clojure

Given a list like:

```
(quote (do (println "Hello") (println "Goodbye")))
```

: how can I turn this into a nicely formatted string which will output something like:

```
(do
  (println "Hello") 
  (println "Goodbye")
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `clojure.pprint/write` with `clojure.pprint/code-dispatch`:

```
(clojure.pprint/write '(do (println "Hello") (println "Goodbye"))
                      :dispatch clojure.pprint/code-dispatch)
```

For that small amount of code you won't get new-lines. But a call like this

```
(clojure.pprint/write '(do (println "Hello") (println "Goodbye") (println "Hey, you left me out!"))
                      :dispatch clojure.pprint/code-dispatch)
```

Returns

```
=> (do
     (println "Hello")
     (println "Goodbye")
     (println "Hey, you left me out!"))
```

To catch that as a string wrap the call in `(with-out-str ...)`

Comment: Fantastic, I will try this and let you know

Comment: I tried this in lighttable but get nothing on the console. How can I get prn/print-edn to just return me a string?

Comment: I did (prn/print-edn (p/parse-string (str (quote (do (println "Hello") (println "Goodbye"))) ))) but it returns nil and nothing shows up in the console

Comment: I also tried ->string but it gives me back my original string with no newlines

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I mixed sth. up. I modified my answer hopefully to your satisfaction.

Comment: Thanks that worked. i will be using your stuff in my project: https://github.com/zubairq/coils/commit/83a69747b7972ac9a18902b092344eba6afca4dd

Comment: Cool, you won't need clj-rewrite anymore, btw. :)

Comment: clj-rewrite is not my project if you mean that :)

Comment: What's the difference of whether using `:dispatch clojure.pprint/code-dispatch` or not? I found somewhere else doing like that.

Comment: @jiyinyiyong code dispatch indents and linebreaks code agnostically

Comment: I noticed it also add `nil` in my code, like `(ns a.bnil)`. Is it supposed to work like that?

Comment: No. Not to my knowledge.

Comment: For the nil, I found it's a bug in 1.6.0. Updating now. http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1361?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:changehistory-tabpanel

Answer (score 5):

As a significantly more performant alternative to `clojure.pprint`, you might want to try Brandon Bloom's [fipp](https://github.com/brandonbloom/fipp):

```
;; add [fipp "0.4.0"] to :dependencies
(require '[fipp.edn :as fipp])

(fipp/pprint '(do (println :foo) (println :bar) (println :quux))
             {:width 30}) ; force wrapping despite small size of data
;; printed output:
(do
 (println :foo)
 (println :bar)
 (println :quux))
```

Unfortunately, Fipp does not yet support code-dispatch.

Comment: It does not support Clojure code. E. g. let-bindings will be printed one-lined or lambdas defined with hash-tags will be generated before being printed.

Comment: This applies equally to clojure.pprint. `(let [x 1 y 2] :foo)` is printed on one line by both clojure.pprint and fipp; `(let [a 1 b 2 c 3 ... z 26] :foo)` is printed by both with each atom on a separate line. `#()`-style functions are in fact translated to `fn*` forms by the Clojure reader, so it is the `fn*` forms that fipp and clojure.pprint see (assuming proper quoting), and of course both handle these fine (e.g. pretty printing `(pprint '#(:foo))` prints out `(fn* [] (:foo))` regardless of whether you use fipp's or clojure.pprint's `pprint`).

Comment: Oh, you're right, sorry -- thanks for putting me right. Should have paid proper attention while reading.